# MySql random query

Tags: mysql, random

I have a table whose structure and data inside it is as follows:
[image]

The table has an auto increment field named ‘id’. It has another field named ‘q_r_id’ which also stores id but here the id may be repeated (for e.g. id-12 may be repeated in more than 1 row but max 5 rows) .

I want to select fixed number of records from this table RANDOMLY but ensuring that from ‘q_r_id’ field if for example id-12 is chosen then all the rows(i.e all the five rows of id-12 should be included in the random result .

I am using the following query but not getting desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM tblreasoningip_r WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(id)*RAND()) FROM tblreasoningip_r) 
group BY q_r_id LIMIT 0,30
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ORDER BY rand() with proper where clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try union,

```
SELECT * FROM
   ( 

        SELECT * FROM tblreasoningip_r 
        WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(id)*RAND()) FROM tblreasoningip_r) 

        UNION

        SELECT * FROM tblreasoningip_r WHERE q_r_id = 12
    )

    GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Abhi your solution is not producing desired result :(

Comment: I want to RANDOMLY select 50 rows from the table ENSURING that if rows having duplicate values (field 1 in my case above) are selected then all the 5 duplicate values should be included.I hope i/m making myself clear...